# Linq Group By multiple value on custom dynamic object

Tags: c#, linq

I made a simple dynamic object:

```
class Row
{
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private int rIndex;

    public Row(int rIndex)
    {
        this.rIndex = rIndex;
    }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return properties[name];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            properties[name] = value;
        }
    }

    public int RIndex
    {
        get { return rIndex; }
        set { rIndex = value; }
    }
}
```

I get the coloumn that i use to group from a configuration file.

Group by different value for example like this :

```
var t = lst.GroupBy(x => new { x1 = x["job"], x2 = x["schema"], x3 = x["line"], x4 = x["plant"], x5 = x["mod"], x6 = x["tag"] }).Select(g => new { g.Key.x1, g.Key.x2, g.Key.x3, g.Key.x4, g.Key.x5, g.Key.x6, });
```

this works well but i think it's too static.

How can i implement a dynamic Group by clause?
Is it possible, inside the Group By clause, get the Dictionary key value that is inside the dynamic object?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "too static"? How do you want to express your grouping? Where do you get the information from about what you want to group by?

Comment: The information to group by are columns name that i take from a configuration file, this means are always different.

Comment: Okay, it would have been nice to have that information in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think it probably makes sense to have something like a `RowView` class, which contains a reference to a `Row`, and the properties you're interested in (a subset of the row's properties). You can then make it implement `IEquatable<RowView>`, such that two `RowView` objects are equal if and only if:

- They contain the same properties, in the same order
- The property values are the same in the rows they refer to

For convenience, I'd probably add a `CreateView(IEnumerable<string> properties)` method to `Row`, so you can call:

```
var t = lst.GroupBy(x => x.CreateView(groupingProperties));
```

(I'd also advise using an automatically-implemented property for `RIndex` to simplify the code - and ideally rename it, as it's not clear what it's for at the moment.)